# Unusual (to me) timestamp string - is this a standard of some kind?

Tags: sql, timestamp

I have inherited an Oracle SQL database which contains many events that have associated timestamps. The timestamps are of the following format:

0:2023050514460000:0.000000:255:0

It's obvious that this means 2023-05-05 14:46:00.00, and I could easily write a function to handle these strings, but I'm curious. All the timestamps start with 0: and all end with 255:0. Is this something custom to this database, cooked up by a fevered mind, or is is some kind of unusual timestamp standard that I should be aware of?

To clarify, this is the result of a single query (no post-processing involved), and all timestamps in the database are stored in the same manner - literally millions of them.

Comment: What query did produce that value? Is that the result of a simple query that retrieved a plain and raw `TIMESTAMP` value or does the query do some kind of data processing?

Comment: this looks more like a delimitated row with 5 values, if you don't have comments for that value or a meaningful column name, you will never know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a custom timestamp that our vendor has invented. Just in case anyone else runs into the same thing, here's a simple way to convert to a more useable format:

```sql
SET @input_string := '0:2023050514460000:0.000000:255:0';
SET @digitstring := REGEXP_SUBSTR(@input_string, '[[:digit:]]{16}', 1);
SET @timeout := REGEXP_REPLACE(@digitstring, '(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})', '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6');
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(@timeout, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS timedone;
```